# What this code does in python?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, nan

I am learning python and wondering what the below code does in Python:

```
def inter_lin_nan(ts, rule):
    ts = ts.resample(rule)
    mask = np.isnan(ts)
    ts[mask] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask), np.flatnonzero(~mask), ts[~mask])
    return(ts)
```

I know this is a function which does interpolation on a time series of data, The second line resample the data according to a rule (e.g. 1hr). What about the fourth and fifth lines? How is this interpolation done? What values `np.interp` needs and what is `~mask`?

Comment: `np` is probably numpy module, you could see it's documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/, for `interp` doc http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html). About `mask`, it should be in your code, please add it so we can see what it is

Comment: yeah, np is numpy, but you can see `mask=np.isnan(ts)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly described in docs:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

> numpy.interp(x, xp, fp, left=None, right=None, period=None)[source]
>   One-dimensional linear interpolation.
>
> **Returns the one-dimensional piecewise linear interpolant to a function**
>   **with given values at discrete data-points**.

so the line `ts[mask] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask), np.flatnonzero(~mask), ts[~mask])` simply interpolates known values onto `NaN`s (which are identified in previous line, and their indices are coded in the `mask`).

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.Series.resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) allows you to take a time series and sample it at different frequencies according to a rule. Say you have a series of 49 daily observations and you want a series of 7 weekly means in return. It does that for you, then you're using numpy.interp to impute any values that come back as nan.